# Issues after loading both plyr and dplyr, even in correct order

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Note: I have reviewed the workarounds in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644739/loading-dplyr-after-plyr-is-causing-issues), but none seem to work unless I completely reboot R, which is impractical given I am sourcing a sequence of R scripts and stopping after every script to reboot R is not a viable solution.

I have an issue that seems to be being caused by the fact that I can't 'properly' detach the `plyr` and `dplyr` package.

Even if I write the following code:

```
detach("package:dplyr", unload = TRUE)
detach("package:plyr", unload = TRUE)
```

Upon then running:

```
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
```

I get the following message:

*You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems.
If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first, then dplyr:
library(plyr); library(dplyr)*

Further if I then try using the `group_by` function I get the following error:

*Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  object 'dplyr_grouped_df_impl' not found*

This error doesn't appear if I run the code after rebooting R, since, it seems, the `dplyr` package doesn't seem to need to be detached initially.

Other things I have tried:

- `dplyr::group_by()` (instead of just `group_by()`)
- reinstalling R
- reinstalling the packages
- testing same code on another computer, the errors do not repeat themselves

Any guidance on what might be going wrong here and what else I could try would be much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145722/non-reproducible-r-package-availability-check/45218652#45218652

Comment: "I am sourcing a sequence of R scripts and stopping after every script to reboot R is not a viable solution." So call R in batch mode / from command line instead. Using `source` in a single session for scripts that should be independent can lead to all sorts of problems in any language that supports it. (I've seen similar issues in Stata.)

Comment: Do all your scripts attempt to load `plyr` and `dplyr`? If so, could you remove those lines from each script, and only load `plyr` and `dplyr` in the correct order once at the beginning?